# Equivalent of MATLAB's "hold on" function

Tags: plotting, dynamic, matlab

I'm making an animation where the number of iterations is known. I tried using `Dynamic`, as I prefer updating in real time over generating data before plotting. 
I want it to look like the following, but *Mathematica* seems to lack a built-in function like MATLAB's `hold on`, which keeps the current plot when adding new content (lines, points) instead of erasing it first. Is there a pretty way to do this？

```
Clear["`*"];
forward[{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}, v_: 5] :=
  Block[{alpha},
   alpha = Switch[Sign[x1 - x2],
     -1, ArcTan[(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)],
     1, Pi + ArcTan[(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)],
     0, Pi/2,
     _, -Pi/2];
   {x1 + v 0.01 Cos[alpha], y1 + v 0.01 Sin[alpha]}
   ];

Module[{plt, p1, p2, p3, p4},
 {p1, p2, p3, p4} = {{-3, 0}, {0, 3}, {3, 0}, {0, -3}};
 Print@Dynamic@plt;
 While[! Or @@Thread[Norm[# - #2] & @@@ Subsets[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, {2}] < .01],
  p1 = forward[p1, p2];
  p2 = forward[p2, p3];
  p3 = forward[p3, p4];
  p4 = forward[p4, p1];
  plt = ListPlot[List /@ {p1, p2, p3, p4}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Orange}];
  Pause[.05]
  ];
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: What does Matlab's "hold on" do?

Comment: @Michael E2 Normally when you plot in Matlab, it erases the current plot. If you command "hold on," it leaves the currnent plot in place and adds the new information to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My take:

```
toward[p1_, p2_, v_: .05] := p1 + v Normalize[p2 - p1];

{n, r} = {4, 3};
DynamicModule[{pts, history},
  pts = r {Cos[#], Sin[#]} & /@ Range[2 Pi/n, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n];
  history = {pts};

  Print[Dynamic[ListPlot[Transpose@history,
     AspectRatio -> Automatic, Joined -> True,
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, CapForm["Round"]],
     PlotRange -> (r + 1) {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]]];

  While[EuclideanDistance @@ RandomSample[pts, 2] > .05,
   pts = toward @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
   AppendTo[history, pts];
   Pause[.05]]];
```

[image]

According to the documentation, `DynamicModule` helps with speed because its variables are held by the frontend. I'm not sure if it makes a difference in any one particular case though. One performance issue is that the `Transpose@history` will become inefficient for longer calculations. But anyway these plot things are quite fun.

[image]

Random starting positions:

[image]

Regular radial starting positions, but random love interest using `pts = RandomSample[pts]`:

[image]

Using `pts = toward @@@ (1.0015 Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1])` as the update routine:

[image]

Using `SeedRandom` we can get a comparison to what it would have looked like using the normal update routine:

[image]

Using `pts = toward[##, .5 RandomChoice[{.6, .4} -> {1, -1}]] & @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1]`, point mostly goes toward its love interest (lust), but sometimes moves away (fear of long-term commitment):

[image]

Using `pts = toward[#, MousePosition["Graphics"] /. None -> #, .1] & /@ pts`:

[image]

These are quite nifty. Add some momentum, throw in some `ColorData`, perhaps a pack of gravitons here or there, who knows what kinda stuff you can come up with.

[image]

### Update

By popular demand, a 3D version. The mechanical code is exactly the same (because e.g. `Normalize` works just the same in 3D as in 2D). But of course 3D allows more kinds of configurations, and I decided to make the code "educational."

```
toward[p1_, p2_, v_: .05] := p1 + v Normalize[p2 - p1];

HD[g_Graphics3D, {upScale_: 2, downScale_: 2, 
    resolution_: {16, 9} (1080/9)}, {style___}] :=
  Show[g /. l_Line :> {style, l}, Boxed -> False, Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True},
     ImageSize -> upScale resolution] // Rasterize // ImageResize[#, Scaled[1/downScale]] &;

{n, sep} = {30, 1.5};

DynamicModule[{pts},
  pts = #[[3]] &@{
     (**)Module[{ico = PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"]},
      15 (Normalize /@ ico)],
     (**)RandomReal[{0, 15}, {n, 3}],
     (**)3 Join[{Cos[#], Sin[#], 0} & /@ (2 Pi Range[n]/n),
       Reverse[{Cos[#], Sin[#], sep} & /@ (2 Pi Range[n]/n)]],
     (**)3 Join[{Cos[#], Sin[#], 0} & /@ (2 Pi Range[n]/n),
       RotateLeft[#, Floor[n/2]] &@Reverse[{Cos[#], Sin[#], sep} & /@ (2 Pi Range[n]/n)]],
     (**)3 Riffle[4 {Cos[#], Sin[#], 0} & /@ (2 Pi Range[n]/n),
       RandomSample[{Cos[#], Sin[#], sep} & /@ (2 Pi Range[n]/n)]]};

  history = {pts};

  g3dExpr = Graphics3D[{Thick, Opacity[.9], Dynamic[
      MapIndexed[{ColorData[1][#2[[1]]], Line[#1]} &, Transpose@history]]},
    ImageSize -> Large];

  PrintTemporary[g3dExpr];

  While[EuclideanDistance @@ RandomSample[pts, 2] > .1,
   pts = toward @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
   AppendTo[history, pts];
   (*disable for speed*)Pause[.05]]];

Beep[];

(*note: purpose here is to be able to adjust the perspective before you rasterize*)
(*CellPrint@ExpressionCell[*)
Defer[HD][Setting[g3dExpr], {4, 4, {590, 590}}, {Thickness[.0015]}]
(*,"Input"]*)
```

[image]
[image]



[image]

Spirals of [this kind](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers) might be useful starting configurations. Also keep in mind that if you try to randomly place points on the surface of a sphere, it may be harder than it sounds.

Comment: Lovely eye candy!

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 for ` Print[Dynamic[...]]`! Great idea:)

Comment: Hi, if you have time, maybe there would be a 3D-Version? I think that will be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Seems no holdon, but to achive the same effect is easy too. Add a Joined->True, looks like a joined curve now

```
Clear["`*"];
forward[{x1_,y1_},{x2_,y2_},v_: 5]:=Block[{alpha},alpha=Switch[Sign[x1-x2],-1,ArcTan[(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)],1,Pi+ArcTan[(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)],0,Pi/2,_,-Pi/2];{x1+v 0.01 Cos[alpha],y1+v 0.01 Sin[alpha]}];
list={};
Module[{plt,p1,p2,p3,p4},{p1,p2,p3,p4}={{-3,0},{0,3},{3,0},{0,-3}};
    Print@Dynamic@plt;While[!Or@@Thread[Norm[#-#2]&@@@Subsets[{p1,p2,p3,p4},{2}]<.01],p1=forward[p1,p2];p2=forward[p2,p3];p3=forward[p3,p4];p4=forward[p4,p1];
plt=Show[ListPlot[Transpose@AppendTo[list,{p1,p2,p3,p4}],PlotRange->{{-4,4},{-4,4}},AspectRatio->Automatic,Joined->True,PlotStyle->{Red,Green,Blue,Orange}]];
Pause[.05]];]
```

[image]

Comment: `ListLinePlot` can also be used instead of `ListPlot` and `Joined -> True`.

Comment: @Michael, speaking as an old *Mathematica* user, that's a hard habit to break. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way

```
L = {};
{n, r} = {4, 3}; 
p = Table[r {Cos@#, Sin@#} &[2. Pi t/n], {t, n}];

Dynamic[
If[Norm[p[[1]]-p[[2]]] > .05, AppendTo[L, p = p + .05 (Normalize /@ (RotateLeft@p - p))]]; 
 Graphics[Line@Transpose[L]]
]
```

[image]